# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module using @ionic-native/health in Angular/Nx/jest app

Tags: angular, jestjs, ionic-native, nrwl-nx

Please help, I get

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
```

using @ionic-native/health in Angular app. repo here, run "npm i", and then "ng test":

https://github.com/chauey/import-issue-ws

[image: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module]

Comment: Please update your post: copy/paste (in text) the place(s) where you're referencing " @ionic-native/health".  I don't see it in app.component.spec.ts - that looks fine.  The problem is that "ng test" is somehow plcking up index.js, which is giving the illegal syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I finally found the answer:

jest.config.js

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@ngrx|@ionic-native|@ionic)']
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
"allowJs": true
```